# Lenovo T560 Trackpoint + Middle Button: Mouse stuck, only scrolling

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, trackpoint

Fresh 16.04 on a fresh T560:

Frequently, when scrolling with Middle Button + Trackpoint, then after releasing the Middle Button the Trackpoint is stuck. 
Only a click frees the Trackpoint and I can navigate again.

Why is it and how to fix this?

Comment: Same here, I've got 14.04 on a X220, it started doing this quite randomly, and gets stuck for different amounts of time - clicking does not release? Not clear how to reproduce. Only happens with trackpoint - trackpad or external mouse don't have the same problem.